# Firestore document recreation & costs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding the costs of Firestore's read operations.

When a document is deleted and recreated remotely (exact same ID and contents) caused for example by an import function where however the original data source has not changed, will this trigger snapshot listeners on the client and cause new read operations?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When a document is deleted

You'll be charged with one **delete** operation.

> and recreated remotely (exact same ID and contents)

You'll be charged with one **write** operation. This is happening no matter if the document has the same id, or if it contains the same data.

> will this trigger snapshot listeners on the client and cause new read operations?

Yes, it will.